# REDIRECT URI not matching failure

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I created a web app that can be hosted on a client's server. If and when a client sets up the site and tries to Authenticate, I'm getting the "redirect URI not matching" error. Makes sense since their domain isn't registered as a "redirect URI" in my app on Azure Active Directory. Is there a work around or do I have to keep adding new REDIRECT URI to AAD?

```
adalProvider.init({
    instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/', 
    tenant: '{MY TENANT ID}',
    clientId: '{MY CLIENT ID}',
    popUp: true,
    endpoints: {
        'https://graph.microsoft.com': 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
    }
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If they're going to process the authentication request on their end, then their going to need to create their own App Registration in their AAD.

Regardless of the redirection logistics, in order for them to process the auth code, they would need to have your App Secret and you *never* want your App Secret on a machine you don't *completely* control.